# find first occurrence of class in div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the below html structure, i want to find the inner html of first div with class as "popcontent" using jQuery

```
<div>
<div class="popContent">1</div>
<div class="popContent">2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 170, accepted):

You will kick yourself..... :)

```
$(".popContent:first").html()
```

Comment: Note that `:first` cannot use `querySelectorAll()`, so it queries all elements, then gets the first one, which might yield poor performance if the number of elements is large.

Answer (score 24):

**first occurrence** of class in div

```
$('.popContent').eq(0).html('value to set');
```

**Second occurrence** of class in div

```
$('.popContent').eq(1).html('value to set');
```

Comment: While not incorrect, this isn't optimal. This will select all `.popContent`, and slice one item. Modern browsers can use querySelector to select just the first element in 1 go (Yes the browser will still select all, but the work a lot faster nyways)

Comment: what will be the fastest way to extract particular element from dom @Martijn

Comment: Without benchmarking, this should do well: If there's and parent with an id close: `$('#the_id').find('.popContent:first')`, otherwist just the currently accepted answer.

Comment: It's not a mayor improvement, but implement this throughout a website it you will notice a lot more

Comment: According to the [:first selector documentation](https://api.jquery.com/first-selector/), *because `:first` is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS specification, queries using `:first` cannot take advantage of the performance boost provided by the native DOM `querySelectorAll()` method.* So it's pretty much equivalent, performance-wise, to `.eq(0)`.

Comment: .eq(n) <- **GOLD** Thanks.

Answer (score 17):

you can use `:first` selector in this case

```
$('.popContent:first').text();
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/pGGUT/)

Answer (score 9):

```
$("div.popContent:first").html()
```

should give you the first div's content ("1" in this case)

Answer (score 6):

You could use [document.querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

> Returns the first element within the document (using depth-first
>   pre-order traversal of the document's nodes|by first element in
>   document markup and iterating through sequential nodes by order of
>   amount of child nodes) that matches the specified group of selectors.

Since it is only looking for first occurence, it has better performance than jQuery

```js
var count = 1000;
var element = $("<span>").addClass("testCase").text("Test");
var container = $(".container");
var test = null;
for(var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
 container.append(element.clone(true));
}

console.time('get(0)');
test = $(".testCase").eq(0);
console.timeEnd('get(0)');
console.log(test.length);

console.time('.testCase:first');
test = $(".testCase:first");
console.timeEnd('.testCase:first');
console.log(test.length);

console.time('querySelector');
test = document.querySelector(".testCase");
console.timeEnd('querySelector');
console.log(test);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container"></div>
```

[jsFiddle version of snippet](https://jsfiddle.net/buksy/vwugc74x/)

Answer (score 4):

Use the [Jquery :first selector](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) like below :

```
$(".popContent:first");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$("div.popContent:first").html();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following jQuery expression

```
alert(jQuery('div.popContent').eq(0).html());
```