# Fetch all images and keep in separate variable using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I  am working on web  crawling (using axios, cheerio to get html from website)so as per requirement I have to fetch images from all section A,B but issue is due to this images are static.. sometimes section A contain 2 images and sometimes section B contain 3 images.. so requirement is keep section A images in different variable and section B images in different variable. I got stuck here how to do this... no idea how to distinguish this.

```html
<div class="container headingWrapper">
   <h3 class="DetailSection_heading ">Section A:</h3>
</div>

<div class="DetailSection_content">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="css-0">
      <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <img src="https://img_url_1" alt="" class="DetailSectionImage" data-index="0">
          <img src="https://img_url_2" alt="" class="DetailSectionImage" data-index="0">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container headingWrapper">
   <h3 class="DetailSection_heading ">Section B:</h3>
</div>

<div class="DetailSection_content">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="css-0">
      <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <img src="https://img_url_3" alt="" class="DetailSectionImage" data-index="0">
            <img src="https://img_url_4" alt="" class="DetailSectionImage" data-index="0">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

jquery Code:

```js
const Fetched_imgs = $('div.DetailSection_content img').map(function() {
  return $(this).attr("src")
}).get();
```

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any tags matching `div.DetailSection_content`. Your selector should just be `'img.DetailSectionImage'`.

Comment: @kmoser updated jquery code... any solution to keep section A image separate and section B separate.

Comment: See my answer for an example of how to find the groups separately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find the images in the first group:
`$('div.DetailSection_content').eq(0).find('img.DetailSectionImage')`

To find the images in the second group:
`$('div.DetailSection_content').eq(1).find('img.DetailSectionImage')`

Example:

```
// First group:
const Fetched_imgs_1 = $('div.DetailSection_content').eq(0).find('img.DetailSectionImage').map(function() {
  return $(this).attr("src")
}).get();

// Second group:
const Fetched_imgs_2 = $('div.DetailSection_content').eq(1).find('img.DetailSectionImage').map(function() {
  return $(this).attr("src")
}).get();

console.log(Fetched_imgs_1); // Array [ "https://img_url_1", "https://img_url_2" ]
console.log(Fetched_imgs_2); // Array [ "https://img_url_3", "https://img_url_4" ]
```

Reference: [find first occurrence of class in div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6423804/find-first-occurrence-of-class-in-div)

Comment: I tried your answer but getting empty array

Comment: it is not fetching any image src, so getting empty array

Comment: You must be doing something wrong. I'm trying your HTML with my JS and `console.log(Fetched_imgs_1)` shows `Array [ "https://img_url_1", "https://img_url_2" ]`, and `console.log(Fetched_imgs_2)` shows `Array [ "https://img_url_3", "https://img_url_4" ]`.

Comment: You could optimise this by not repeating the `div.DetailSection_content` query

Comment: @Phil Agreed, you could also put it in a loop from 0 to 1, which would only require writing the selector once. All these implementation details are left as an exercise for the reader :)

Answer (score 3):

You can make this dynamic by finding the headings first then using sibling selectors to find the images

```js
const images = $(".DetailSection_heading").map((_, h) => [ // 1️⃣
  $(h).closest(".headingWrapper") // move up to the wrapper
    .next(".DetailSection_content") // get the next sibling
    .find("img") // find the images
    .map((_, { src }) => src) // extract the src property
    .get() // get the result array
]).get()

console.log(images)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
<div class="container headingWrapper"> <h3 class="DetailSection_heading ">Section A:</h3></div><div class="DetailSection_content"> <div class="container"> <div class="css-0"> <div class="row justify-content-center"> <div class="col-lg-6"> <img src="https://img_url_1" alt="" class="DetailSectionImage" data-index="0"> <img src="https://img_url_2" alt="" class="DetailSectionImage" data-index="0"> </div></div></div></div></div><div class="container headingWrapper"> <h3 class="DetailSection_heading ">Section B:</h3></div><div class="DetailSection_content"> <div class="container"> <div class="css-0"> <div class="row justify-content-center"> <div class="col-lg-6"> <img src="https://img_url_3" alt="" class="DetailSectionImage" data-index="0"> <img src="https://img_url_4" alt="" class="DetailSectionImage" data-index="0"> </div></div></div></div></div>
```

This will create a nested array with each set of images grouped by the *section*, eg section *A* at index `0`, section *B* at `1`, etc

<sub>1️⃣  A hack to get around [jQuery's .map() automatically flattening arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/q/703355/283366)</sub>